# Query All Events in Soql

Tags: soql

I have a two contacts 'John', 'Chris'.

Opened 'John' contact and created an event called 'Meeting'.

then Opened 'Chris' and created an event called 'call' and tagged 'John'(means added 'john' in whoid. We can add multiple contacts to whoId).
So here Chris contains one event called 'call'
and 'John' contains 2 events 'call' and 'Meeting'.

When i query events on 'John' [select id from event where whoid='johnid']. only geeting 'Meeting' event but not 'call' event.

Comment: What do you mean by 'tagged to contact john'?

Comment: while creating a event we can tag multiple contacts to whoid

Comment: Restating the phrase with different wording is not overly helpful.

Comment: modified question @nickCook. can you pls help me on this.

Comment: Object ID is unique so if you query on it, you'll get only one result. And if try `select id from event where Whoid='johnid'`

Comment: sorry  it's typo. i tried with whoid='johnid'

Comment: @Nick Cook is correct. You don't have to click add to invitees. It will automatically create for every whoid. I just tested this on my developer org and it works just fine. Check RelationId part on this doc: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_objects_eventattendee.htm

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you have multiple contacts on an event, Salesforce creates entries in the `EventRelation` table.

If you want all events that John is related to, try:

```
SELECT Id, RelationId, EventId FROM EventRelation WHERE RelationId = :johnId
```

Comment: It will create on eventrelation only when you click on 'Add to invitees' but we are not using eventrelation.